# Redirecting URL requests with wildcard in URL?

Tags: .htaccess, ddos

Apparently a ton of bots are hammering my site with requests that look like this:

- www.domain.com/?16322150=856677556
- www.domain.com/?1507558478=1959488868
- www.domain.com/?1003637363=132097965
- www.domain.com/?647628023=904035481

Anyway I could effectively redirect these requests with .htaccess? Maybe redirect them back to themselves?

We've tried Cloudflare and Intreppid, but they are claiming that we have HTTPD or Mysql exploits that aren't addressed. Any insight?

Comment: Requests are not what you should block but IP or HTTP_REFERER should be

Comment: The problem is that the IPs are a huge range. We're talking hundreds of requests per second

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to do something like this to prevent your scripts from being interpreted by apache (saves maybe a little bit of resources):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/ [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.